# How to avoid n^n^n complexity loop in jquery?

Tags: jquery

This is my data coming from backend and there can be upto 30 thousand or something like that

```
0:{id: 1, name: "Jagoda Sharp"}
1:{id: 1, name: "Romeo Dolan"}
2:{id: 2, name: "Shiloh Sheppard"}
3:{id: 3, name: "Cyrus Ellwood"}
4:{id: 4, name: "Rhian Davis"}
5:{id: 5, name: "Humayra Cooley"}
6:{id: 6, name: "Vickie Gilmore"}
7:{id: 7, name: "Danielius Mosley"}
8:{id: 8, name: "Kia Hobbs"}
9:{id: 9, name: "Clifford Tucker"}
10:{id: 10, name: "Ebonie Vang"}
11:{id: 11, name: "Dewey Robson"}
12:{id: 12, name: "Abdullahi Brennan"}
13:{id: 13, name: "Reo Mcneill"}
14:{id: 14, name: "Taran Sellers"}
15:{id: 15, name: "Amira Greenaway"}
16:{id: 16, name: "Rowena Lovell"}
17:{id: 17, name: "Velma Salinas"}
18:{id: 18, name: "Raisa Leblanc"}
19:{id: 19, name: "Angel Lister"}
20:{id: 20, name: "Stacie Foster"}
....
...
...
```

In My script file, I use select2 to search users name but due to 30k of user data.My site seem to be crashed.So how should i avoid using  n^n^n complexity loop

```
   data.users.forEach(function (user) {
            $("#users").select2({
            });
            var newOption = new Option(user.name, user.id, false, false);
            $('#users').append(newOption).trigger('change');
       });
```

Comment: Use Ajax and search via server side: https://select2.org/data-sources/ajax

Comment: Agree with @imvain2 - 30k entities is far too many for client-side JS to handle. Perform the filter server side instead.